# A hole carved out in wall for a wooden crossbeam

Tags: terminology, construction

I once saw a word for a hole carved out in a wall on purpose to accept a wooden crossbeam that fits into the hole. I think it had a "p" in it, something like "pit hole" ?...

Comment: You need to be clearer. Are you asking about a mediaeval castle or a modern building? Are you asking about a slot (three sides) or a hole (four sides)? If it is a hole, does the hole have an end? Is the crossbeam metal or wood?

Comment: @Greybeard: I think a "wooden crossbeam" as mentioned in the question is almost certainly made out of wood, not metal.

Comment: It's in the context of old / ancient architecture with stone or brick walls. It may also apply to e.g. rock-cut walls in a 19th cent. mine. Such holes are usually square and matched to the intended profile of the wooden crossbeam.

Comment: A *[padstone](https://www.mcandrewassociates.co.uk/post/padstones-what-are-they-and-how-are-they-used)* is the mount on which the end of the beam rests, made of tougher material than the wall, and might be in a hole in the wall, which might sometimes be called a padstone hole; is that what you're thinking of? (A padstone might informally be called a pad but I'm not sure if that's standard terminology.) I don't know a particular name for the hole otherwise (but padstone seems current terminology so there may be older names). You're probably better asking in the engineering or DIY SEs.